# Trivial Kernel and density of range

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators

On the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator) page for unbounded operators, it states that since:
$$
\text{ker}~T = (\text{range} T^*)^{\perp}
$$
Then we may conclude that if $T^*$ has trivial kernel then $T$ has dense range. Does this hold for all operators $T$? Further, why does it actually hold? I don't see the connection between denseness and the above equivalence. I'm interested in the general Banach space case, not just operators defined on Hilbert spaces.

Comment: What are your assumptions on $T$. If it is  a bounded operator on  a Hilbert space then $T^{**}=T$ and you can change $T$ to $T^{*}$ in (1) to get $ker(T^{*}) =(ran (T)^{\perp}$ . Taking perp on both sides we get $ker(T^{*})^{\perp} =closure(ran (T))$ from which the result follows.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What about a for an injective $T$ on an arbitrary Banach Space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T:X\to Y$ is  abounded operator such that $T^{*}$ is injective then, for any $y^{*} \in Y^{*}$ such that $y^{*}=0$ on the range of $T$ we have $T^{*}y^{*}(x)=y^{*}(Tx)=0$ for all $x$. But $T^{*}$ is injective so we get $y^{*}=0$. This proves that the range of $T$ is dense.